# Extracting domain without subdomains other then www with RE2 / regex?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

This regular expression extracts domain with TLD from urls:

`TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Address, "https?://", ""), R"^(w{3}\.)?", ""), "([^/?]+)"))`

This expression makes from `http://www.example.com/page.html` → `example.com`, which is expected output.

**But** it works only in case if subdomain is `www`. In other cases it doesn't process.

If i use instead `TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Address, "https?://", ""), R"^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\.)?", ""), "([^/?]+)"))` - the whole domain name disappears and only TLD remains.

Is there any way to process any subdomain, which string can be expressed with `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}`?

Expected output would be

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| sites.example.com | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| m.example.com     | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| ww2.example.com   | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| mail.example.com  | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| blog.example.com  | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| shop.example.com  | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| cdn.example.com   | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| api.example.com   | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 1.example.com     | example.com |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: `re2` is this https://github.com/google/re2. I run it as calculated field in Google data Studio, where re2 is a regex favour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the field is `Address`, the below does the trick:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(Address, "^(.*//)", ""),
 "^([^/]*)"),
R"([^\.]*\.[^\.]*)$")
```

A quick breakdown of Line 3 to Line 5 using an unnested explanation of the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

- Line 3 `REGEXP_REPLACE(Address, "^(.*//)", "")`: Removes the `http//` or `https//` section
- Line 4: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Line 3, "^([^/]*)")`: Extracts all characters till the first `/`
- Line 5: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Line 4, R"([^\.]*\.[^\.]*)$")`: Extracts all characters from the end of the string, till the second `.`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/de2250ac-a496-4992-afa2-d0b580219522) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N_qQIIbDovuP-ifoswNcRWG4FN4TIMcjEX7x_h6FRCE/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your code that gets rid of the protocol and the path, leaving us just the domain I would suggest to use a regex which captures the subdomain(s), the domain and the TLD. We could then just replace the match by the domain and TLD.

Just be carefull that an URL may contain ftp protocol or an authentification part with a user and an optional password or the protocol may also be ommited. So this depends on your data, of course.

Examples:

```
ftp://something.example.com/folder
http://user:pswd@subdomain.example.com/path
//xyz-123.sub-domain.example.com
```

I played around with Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/X4UoCx/1/

The regular expression is:

```regex
^((?:\w[\w-]{0,61}\.)*)(\w[\w-]{0,61}\.[a-z]{2,62})$
```

Explained:

- `()` are used to capture parts. Here, we capture the subdomain(s) in capture n°1, the domain with the TLD in capture n°2.
- `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. Here its used for the subdomain pattern because it's always a word with eventually hyphens followed by a point, zero or several times. So `\w[\w-]{0,61}\.` means a word character (a-z + A-Z + 0-9) and then a word character or an hyphen, 0 up to 61 times. This is because the maximum length seems to be 62 chars. Then its followed by a point.
- We want to repeat this pattern as we can have multiple subdomains. This is why this expression is put inside a non-capturing group which can be 0 or n times: `(?:\w[\w-]{0,61}\.)*`
- We'll capture this subdomains for eventual later use with parentheses: `((?:\w[\w-]{0,61}\.)*)`
- Now, the second interesting group is our domain and TLD: `(\w[\w-]{0,61}\.[a-z]{2,62})`

  - The domain is `\w[\w-]{0,61}` because it cannot start with a hyphen.
  - The TLD is `\.[a-z]{2,62}`

So to end it up, you just want to replace the matched full domain with the matching group number 2, which contains your domain and TLD.
I don't know the exact syntax of the RE2 regex replace method so the replacement string could be `"$2"` or `"\2"`.